# Java Spring Entity insert throws "JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException"

Tags: java, spring, entity, unique-constraint

I think its a very simple problem. But I dont see it. Can someone please help me?
I have an entity "User":

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(63) default null", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private String keycloakUserSubject;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserProjectRoleOfUserInProject_Assignation> userProjectRoleOfUserInProject_Assignation = new HashSet<>();

//getter and setter...
}
```

And I have an endpoint "UserController" that tries to insert a new User:

```
@Service
public class UserController implements UsersApiDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(Optional<String> acceptLanguage) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(5L); // I usually tried without this line (cause it is generated) --> same error)
        user.setLastname("st");
        user.setFirstname("te");
        user.setEmail(RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, false)+"@mail.com");
        System.out.println(user);
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

//...
}
```

Its corresponding userRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAll();
    Optional<User> findByKeycloakUserSubject(String keycloakUserSubject);
}
```

Calling that endpoint I get this error:

```
User [email=rOaryOjCtG@mail.com, firstname=te, id=5, keycloakUserSubject=null, lastname=st, userProjectRoleOfUserInProject_Assignation=[]]
2022-06-01 08:23:47.937  WARN 16560 --- [nio-8000-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2022-06-01 08:23:47.938 ERROR 16560 --- [nio-8000-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Eindeutiger Index oder Primõrschl³ssel verletzt: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']"
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']"; SQL statement:
insert into user (email, firstname, keycloak_user_subject, lastname, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-200]2022-06-01 08:23:47.953 ERROR 16560 --- [nio-8000-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']"; SQL statement:
insert into user (email, firstname, keycloak_user_subject, lastname, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-200]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Eindeutiger Index oder Primõrschl³ssel verletzt: 
"PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']"
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']"; SQL statement:
insert into user (email, firstname, keycloak_user_subject, lastname, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I think I get blind sometimes...
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does your Table has a record with 1@mail.com? Email should be unique for each record as defined here.

Comment: Look at the values in the error message. That row is being inserted by some other bit of code.

Comment: In the full stacktrace the corresponding line should be:

        at tech.richtfest.api.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]

But this seems to be this endpoint, no?

Answer (score 0):

There is something in your code who try to insert [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul'] and it already exist.
This is what your error say

Comment: Is it something to do with the OneToMany, having an entry already in the associated table? What I find strange is why the insert statement is not showing the email that yuou have generated ? Strange

Comment: If I set email to no more unique and delete the one to many part I get the same error.

Comment: My database is preloaded with:

ID   EMAIL   FIRSTNAME   KEYCLOAK_USER_SUBJECT   LASTNAME  

1 5@mail.com Tobias 333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4 Dobberphul

2 2@mail.com Manny null Mannan

3 3@mail.com Bertha null Berg

Comment: I think the errormessage only says that the constraint (ID) is violated by an insert and the corresponding row that is being violated is "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.USER(ID) [1, '1@mail.com', 'Tobias', '333a4548-5fd6-463e-8d33-657c5174c5a4', 'Dobberphul']" ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like `select next value for hibernate_sequence`
not triggered. in your case its always 1 is getting.

Comment: Thats interesting. Thanks. From which position in the stacktrace you get this?
And far more important: How can I verify and change it ;D

Comment: before insert  into user table, should have select next value for hibernate_sequence . if manually update id remove @GeneratedValue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I found the answer:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

does the right job.